# Animate several on change events in arc/pie D3.js graph using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, d3.js

I am in the same boat many have been in with D3 trying to get to the next level.  I have a graph that is close to what I want but I can't figure out how to animate the change.  There are many events and have the different parts placed into different functions.  I call them with the following if else if:

```
 if ($("#chart1Pie").is(":checked")) {
    updateOne();
    } else if ($("#chart2Pie").is(":checked")) {
        updateTwo();
    };
```

Do I have it wrong by having the different parts in different functions?  The full code is on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rocky1616/ghfqmygh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using D3 absolutely incorrectly. You have ONE graph, but two sets of data - for Smith and for Jones. You don't need to remove stuff inside #chart using jQuery and then rebuild the whole graph from the scratch. In general, if you want to remove and add elements you should use D3 methods .enter() and .exit().

In your case you **don't** need to remove anything. All you need to do on update is recalculate attribute "d" for of your paths.

Check these examples: [one](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad), [two](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b).

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case.  What I am having a real issue with is how to write the on change function.  Would you suggest something like this based off the examples you provided. `code`d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
                var value = this.value === "pie"
                    ? function(d) { return d.jones; }
                    : function(d) { return d.smith; };`code`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Essentially, on input change you just figure out how to filter your data - Jones vs Smith. Then you pass either Jones data set or Smith data set to data() function. So the data have been changed. Now we need to reflect that in graph. The graph is already built. So we just need to recalculate each slice based on new data. Use tween to animate it.